# Qt How to register enum class in QML without QObject class

Tags: qt, qml, qenum

```
EnumClasses.h

    #ifndef ENUMCLASSES_H
    #define ENUMCLASSES_H
    
    #include <QObject>
    
    namespace mynamespace {
    
    enum class Fruit : int
    {
        Apple,
        Banana,
        Orange
    };
    Q_ENUM(Fruit)
    
    }
    
    #endif // ENUMCLASSES_H
```

appears Warning message

```
EnumClasses.h:14:1: error: 'friend' used outside of class
qobjectdefs.h:116:30: note: expanded from macro 'Q_ENUM'
qobjectdefs.h:114:5: note: expanded from macro 'Q_ENUM_IMPL'
```

If I use Q_ENUMS (deprecated) Warning appears

```
/home/Qt/EnumClasses.h:14:1: Use Q_ENUM instead of
Q_ENUMS
```

What I need do for register enum class in QML?

Comment: you probably speak about  [Q_GADGET](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#Q_GADGET)

Comment: No I want to use qRegisterMetaType() for register my <Fruit > enum

Comment: I mean about https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#enumeration-types

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```cpp
namespace mynamespace {
Q_NAMESPACE

enum class Fruit : int
{
    Apple,
    Banana,
    Orange
};
Q_ENUM_NS(Fruit)
}
```

See: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterUncreatableMetaObject